# Spark performance issue at NOT IN query

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataset

When I execute that query in SPARK(2.0), there were no shuffle read/write and hanged over 40min to execute that query.

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.key1 NOT IN ( SELECT B.key1 from B ) AND A.key2 NOT IN (SELECT B.key2 from B )
```

It was just an action to write.

```
Dataset<Row> re = Operation.project(ss, var, A, B);
re.write()
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", "var.Driver")
    .option("url", var.url)
    .option("dbtable", var.tablename)
    .option("user", var.username)
    .option("password", var.password)
    .save();
```

The number of records in A and B is less than 100,000. 
So, I thought I had a problem with this query.
But this query took only 30sec.(It's also write action)

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE (A.key1, A.key2) IN ( SELECT B.key1, B.key2 FROM B )
```

Will not the problem be resolved by changing only the 'not in' query?

Comment: Seems like it will.

Comment: Which query can replace that query exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK  NOT IN is expensive in sql.

Since you are using dataframes (`Dataset<Row>`) you can leave sql and try with dataframe joins(as it has its own benefits(small dataframe will be broadcasted hence it will be fast)

I think you have to apply left anti join in this case...
that means...

> Returns all the records from the left side that do not have matches
>   from the right. The result table just has the columns from the left
>   side.

[image]

See [joinTypes](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/joinTypes.scala) here..

Comment: I tried the left anti join but i had 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded'. How can i fix it?

Comment: might be that it went to cross join and so, can you paste you implementation details here. And also you have 2 leftanti joins so you apply them step by step

Comment: I applied that query like ' "select * from A left anti join B on A.key1 = B.key2 and A.key2 = B.key2'. And this query will then perform 10 iterations. But GC overhead error occurs at 3rd iterations.

Comment: What's the meaning of 'step by step'?

Comment: Can i avoid cross join? And I wonder if I can change the results the same.